# Is there is any way i could align columns based on unique text using notepad++ or any means?

Tags: regex, format, notepad++

My file has thousands of line like this
[enter image description here][1]

---

```
`<userdata ID="11010014"    PRI="1" Locator="Class_abc"   DATA="5 "/>
<userdata ID="11010014"  PRI="1"  Locator="Class_abcde  DATA="5 "/>
<userdata ID="11010014"   PRI="1" Locator="Class_ab"    DATA="5 "/>
<userdata ID="11010014" PRI="1"  Locator="Class_primary " DATA="5 "/>`
```

---

i have to align all the fields properly like this what to do help me.

### [enter image description here][2]

```
`<userdata ID="11010014" PRI="1" Locator="Class_abc"       DATA="5 "/>
 <userdata ID="11010014" PRI="1" Locator="Class_abcde"     DATA="5 "/>
 <userdata ID="11010014" PRI="1" Locator="Class_ab"        DATA="5 "/>`
```

---

ID length is constant
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Ff2.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4RYP.png

Comment: Instead of images, add example as text.

Comment: Do you have any way of doing it?

Comment: Are **all** `ID` values the same length (i.e. 8 character)?

Comment: Yes but locater and data varies in length

Comment: The main problem is with the data column since its not getting aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be helpful

---

**Step 1)** search for:

```
\h+(?!ID=|")
```

Replace with:

```
\t
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TxOK08/12)

---

The pattern matches:

- `h+` - At least a single horizontal whitespace character.
- `(?!ID=|")` - Negative lookahead for either literally 'ID=' ***or*** '"'.

---

**Step 2)**:

- Click <kbd>Plugins</kbd> > <kbd>Plugins Admin</kbd>
- Tick 'Elastic Tabstops' and hit <kbd>Install</kbd>

As soon as it's installed you'll notice it will auto-allign the tabs we just inserted.

Comment: Nice one. You can replace `[^\S\n]+` with `\h+` (1 or more horizontal spaces). But, it will not work if `ID` length is not fixed, for example `<userdata ID="11" PRIORITY="1"` will not  be aligned properly. Waiting for OP, and I'll give you my vote.

Comment: Learned something from you about the `\h+`. Haven't really used it before but it's a great alternative!

Comment: Sorry I edited the question your answer was great for the previous one but i added a field now **Locater** the length of it varies. Can you take a quick look at the images added too you would get an idea what im trying to achieve.

Comment: I didn't know this plugin. Good job!